# Webview Doesn't Work With Scorm On Android 8.0 (OREO)

Tags: java, android, webview

Hope you are all having a nice day.

I work in a e-learning company. My mobile app was working flawlessly but recently there have been issues from users about scorm classes. They all use Samsung s8 and s8+ devices. App works fine until webview calls my url. For example if i use google.com as url it works seamlessly, directs to google main page. I have tried a youtube video and it crashed. It just prints "Blabla app stopped working". I would really appreciate your expertise or experiences on android 8.0(oreo) this subject.

Here's the buggy code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
WebSettings 
webSettings = webView.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.loadUrl("youtube.com/watch?v=D7LB-QPxH9c");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you be more specific about the problem you're facing? Maybe add some of your code to the question that causes your truble? That would really help to find a solution for you.

Comment: @CodeF0x Below is my snippet. This part of the code supposed to open up a SCORM lesson video or youtube in this case and it does in 7.0 or below android devices. It doesn't on android 8.0.                                                                                            `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7LB-QPxH9c");`